# Find all references in visual studio 2010 for multiple words at a time

Tags: visual-studio

Is there a way to find all references of groups of words?

i.e all files that have Word1,word2,word3 (basicaLly Word1 & word2 & word3) using the "find all references" dialog of Visual Studio 2010?

I need to refactor a large codebase.

I don't know how to use regex search.

Comment: If you're wondering, Visual Studio won't warn you when you make a really bad regular expression search that will find everything, it will peg the CPU and eat up memory until you kill the task. Or at least that's what a a _friend_ told me.

Answer (score 2):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2k3te2cs(v=vs.80).aspx

Look for the regexp in your particular language. I do recommend using regexp if you want to massage the results.

You can do it with code, or in the "Find and Replace" (CTLR+F) panel of VS2010 -using regexp!- in the advanced search